# MVVM model validation and data binding?

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm, .net-4.0

When looking up tutorials for the best practices to do property validation in WPF MVVM I see a lot of people use the interface `IDataErrorInfo` I was just wondering if it is possible to setup automatic validation like that used in ASP .Net MVC using attributes?

Can anyone sugest what the best practices are for model validation in MVVM? Should the validation be on the base model class? or on the view model class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight has a control called the DataForm that works using the DataAnnotations Attributes and someone was kind enough to [port that control to WPF](http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/). I believe that is something along the lines of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

These are good questions!! Validation belongs in BOTH the Model and the ViewModel(s). Here is how I usually approach it:

First I put as much validation in the Model as I can - these will be rules that are independent of a given presentation. For example, assume an employee in your domain is not valid if it doesn't have a EmployeeNumber property that is not null, and six characters in length, and each of the six characters must be a digit.

Secondly, I have a base ViewModel class that implements IDataErrorInfo. In this base class I basically ask the Model if it is valid, triggering an error if it isn't (which is easy to translate to the View by virtue of IDataErrorInfo). I also make the implementing methods of IDataError info virtual, because...

Lastly, there will be edge cases unique to a given presentation that cannot be captured by the Model. For a (contrived) example, assume you have one presentation in which an employee is valid if only his first and last name are entered, and another that requires a middle initial as well. While you certainly can and should have a FullName component / valueObject property in Employee to validate that the property is not null, you need a subclassed ViewModel for each presentation to know if the user entries for the properties of the Fullame are valid in this case.

Finally, you can and should use a Validator for your Model validation - I like NHibernateValidator but there are certainly other (very) good ones available. Most of them, including NHibernate's, will support the attribute validation you are looking for. I prefer a cleaner alternative to attributes however, whereby I setup all validation rules for my validator in a separate project (ie, MyDomainImpl). Cleaner in the sense of less noise in the Model, and a cleaner separation of concerns.

Feel free to ask questions if you need to Also give yourself some time to work thru this until you have an approach that works for you - this is *not* a trivial topic.

HTH,
Berryl

Answer (score 1):

My take is that validation should be on ViewModel and not on Model because :

- Validations are for incorrect input
  and the first logical point of UI is
  ViewModel. It is good practice to
  validate and stop request at
  ViewModel and not send across invalid
  data to the Model
- Also many a times Models are legacy and the assumption is that they
  cannot be modified. ViewModel creates
  a good wrapper over the model.

If you are using any Dependency Injection tool for your aplication like Unity, Windsor Castle etc., you can use interceptors to validate ViewModels. Interceptors are invoked first before any call to ViewModel methods.

An example of using interceptor with Castle can be found here - 
http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/interceptors.html

Answer (score 1):

Where to put the validation logic?

> Software systems mostly need some kind
>   of validation to ensure that the
>   business logic has to deal with
>   correct data only. These validation
>   rules are defined by the business
>   model and so the Domain layer is the
>   right place to implement them. Just
>   keep in mind that you don’t start to
>   duplicate the validation code between
>   the business objects.
>
> [link](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Architecture%20-%20Get%20The%20Big%20Picture&referringTitle=Home)

.

You might be interested in the sample applications of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. They show how to use the .NET DataAnnotations validation attributes together with the MVVM pattern.